# Facebook API: Best practices when using a load balancer

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, load-balancing

I'm developing a Facebook connected website using the PHP SDK and I am looking for guidance on best practices for scaling.

I have two pages

http://www.example.com/foo.php  -> User reads about the web app here and Authorizes the Facebook application

The user is then has the option to go to another page:

http://www.example.com/bar.php  -> Custom page generated for the user based on data queried using FQL

I am looking to distribute this application across a series of servers on PHPFog and they are sitting behind a load balancer.  This means that the user may end up getting foo.php from Server1 and then being redirected to Server2 for bar.php.  I am concerned that this will break the Facebook auth session.

Does anyone know how I can correctly code for this scenario or if there are any best practices published anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access token will be valid across both servers, you can even take the access token an use it in your own browser while it is valid.

I would store the access token in an encrypted cookie, that way every server would be able to obtain the right access token for the user.